# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

I created a factory that involve getting the location and fetching data from an API and return a result. When I call the factory from the controller I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Factory:

```
app.factory("getStations", function($http) {


    var stations = function () {
        console.log("stations function");


        console.log("GetStations Factory Loaded");
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var latLng = { 'lat': position.coords.latitude, 'lng': position.coords.longitude };
            console.log("This is in location service: " + latLng["lat"] + "," + latLng["lng"]);
            var url = "http://dev.url.com/location/" + latLng["lat"] + "/" + latLng["lng"] + "/5";

            console.log(url);
            return $http({ method: "GET", url: url }).then(function (result) {
                return result.data.stations;
            });
        });
    };
    console.log("return");
    console.log({ stations: stations });
    return { stations: stations };
});
```

Controller:

```
app.controller("PullToRefresh", function($scope, getStations) {
    //
    console.log("Pull To Refresh Loaded");
    $scope.items = [];

    $scope.doRefresh = function() {

        var promise = getStations.stations();
        promise.then(function(result) {
            $scope.items = result;
            $scope.$broadcast("scroll.refreshComplete");
        });
    };
});
```

Am I missing something, if I take the `$http` out of the `navigator` it works the second time. It take a few seconds for the location to be found and on the first call, there is no defined `var` and I get a URL error.

Comment: Your `stations` function in your `getStations` factory doesn't return anything

Comment: I figured that was the case, I guess I am a little lost on how to get the factory to return the data from from http call when the location is a success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you aren't returning anything in your `stations` function so there is no `then` method available.

Seeing as `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` doesn't return a usable promise, you'll need to use `$q`

```
.factory('getStations', function($q, $http) {
    return {
        stations: function() {
            return $q(function(resolve) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                    var latLng = { 'lat': position.coords.latitude, 'lng': position.coords.longitude };
                    var url = "http://dev.url.com/location/" + latLng["lat"] + "/" + latLng["lng"] + "/5";

                    resolve($http.get(url).then(function(response) {
                        return response.data.stations;
                    }));
                });
            });
        }
    };
})
```